# Wi-fi Direct not triggering any action in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I used the code availalbe on Android Devlopoers Forum . My Activity is :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
      mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
      mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
      mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
      mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

      mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
      mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
      mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);  
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

And I have a receiver class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
 }
```

But it is not working . There is no error and Toast is also not displaying. I think I have to enable Wif-Direct. Need help in this

My Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: in `OnReceive` try to get other actions and check if they are being triggered. `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` , `WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION` and `WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION`

Comment: Should I enable wi-fi or wi-fi hotspot ?

Comment: Once you enable wifi, there will be an option for wifi direct. you don't have to enable wifi hotspot

Comment: There is no option of wifi direct

Comment: which phone are you using?

Comment: @blganesh101 Does it support wifi direct ?

Comment: http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_y300-5386.php 
I think it does not support wifi-direct